# Draftsight, Excel VBA code to open DWG files and save them as DXF's

Tags: excel, vba

The Excel macro below is supposed to open all the DWG files in a folder and save them as DXF's. I keep getting a error on the  line "Set objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(file.Path)". What am I doing wrong?
I have Draftsight Enterprise edition for editing DWG/DXF files only.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
Sub DWG2DXF()
    Dim folderPath As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a folder"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    If folderPath <> "" Then
        Dim objApp As Object
        Set objApp = GetObject(, "DraftSight.Application")
        Dim objDoc As Object
        For Each file In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(folderPath).Files
            If Right(file.Name, 4) = ".dwg" Then
                Set objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(file.Path)
                objDoc.SaveAs Replace(file.Path, ".dwg", ".dxf"), 24
                objDoc.Close False
            End If
        Next file
        Set objDoc = Nothing
        Set objApp = Nothing
        MsgBox "All DWG files in selected folder and subfolders have been converted to DXF files."
    Else
        MsgBox "No folder selected."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `file.Path` when it errors?

Comment: It is the complete file path and name of file that it should show, I think. "C:\Temp\Draftsight Macros\Test.dwg"   Type: Variant/String

Comment: The error I get is "Object doesn't support this property or method". I assume it is because it is not a property/function available in the Draftsight library for objApp.Documents._______

Comment: Then I'm guessing that DraftSight uses a different method? What does the documentation say about it?